# how can I disable a checkbox in a mustache view if a condition is met?

Tags: mustache

this is part of the json response

```
"name_with_grade": "2º - A",
"rates": [
{
  "name": "Evaluación",
  "quantity": 1,
  "due_date": null,
  "optional": false,
  "rate": 300
},
```

and the mustache

```
      {{#rates}}
        {{#rate}}
          <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>{{name}}</td>
            <td>{{rate}}</td>
          </tr>
        {{/rate}}
      {{/rates}}
```

rate could be blank hence the `{{#rate}}` but some are optional and i would like to disable the checkbox for those that aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed the logic to be required instead of optional and this seems to do it, some better ideas welcome.

```
<td>
  <input type="checkbox"
    {{#required}}
      disabled="disabled" checked="checked"
    {{/required}}>
</td>
```

Comment: You could also use an inverted section... `{{^optional}} disabled="disabled" checked="checked"{{/optional}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class in order to enable/disable the controls based on a condition:

1. add an hidden field that will contain the condition (loaded in the server 
   side):
   **input type="hidden" runat="server" id="js_hfDisabled" value=""**
2. add a class into the control:
   input type="checkbox" **class="js_disabled"**
3. add a new function: into the $(document).ready(function()...

   **function enabled_disabled() {
           var jshfDis = $('#js_hfDisabled').val();
           $('.js_disabled').prop('disabled', jshfDis);
       }**

   and call it inside the $(document).ready(function()...